# Intel compiler report "library not found for lstdc++"

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, linker, intel

I'm on XCode 3.5, with the intel compiler 12.0.4
I'm having an error at the kinking stage, with this ld error message :

"library not found for -lstdc++"

When switching to gcc i have no error.
Does someone can explain me, why it can't find this lib (which is present in usr/lib/) ?

Thanks a lot.